# Serving an image file only when a condition is met in PHP

Tags: php

I want to serve images over HTTP like example.com/images.php?id=1234 .But it is subject to conditions (logged in, permissions) etc. If the conditions are true, it would send an appropriate header with the data body and the image data. Else, the content of another image is sent.

Comment: A simple `if` statement will do the trick.  What part of it are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(<your conditions>) {
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); // or image/png, etc (depends on type)
    readfile("/path/to/conditions-met.jpg");
    exit;
} else {
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); // or image/png, etc
    readfile("/path/to/conditions-failed.jpg");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could return a 404, or possibly a 401 HTTP status code (depending on what is actually wanting to be achieved).

Comment: Right. You can do whatever you want in that `else` block. (But since the OP specified sending a different image, that's what the example uses. My guess here is a "please don't deeplink our images" kind of placeholder.)

Comment: More like "please log in to view this". And yes, I had that particular hotlink protection measure in mind while I asked this.